# Angular reporting 404 on url source

Tags: angularjs, http-status-code-404, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an Angular template:

```
    <div class="item holder" ng-repeat="article in articles">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-3 holder imgHolder">
            <a href="{{article.articleLink}}"><img src="{{article.image}}" alt="" /></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It shows a list of articles.

I'm getting the following error on the console:

```
GET http://example.com/%7B%7Barticle.image%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

The template renders the articles correctly but I also get the error.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First take `article.image` and print it to the console `console.log` and copy + paste the Url into your browser. Does your browser get a `404`? If this happens then something is wrong without your Url. If this is not the case then:

It looks like AngularJs is replacing some key characters with Url safe characters.
Try using `ng-src="article.image"` instead.

If you are still getting a 404 and it still has `%7D`'s in it then output `article.image` to the console to make sure the string is not bad.

Comment: Using ng-src instead of src attributes fixed the problem